# How to prevent our app to open any camera and gallery and then return into our app then do not ask me touch id authentication

Tags: android

Does anyone knows if we open camera and gallery from our app then prevent touch id authentication in Android if we open camera and gallery from our app only?

Like Whats app: If we click camera button to click an image and after taking image return into whats app then if we return to our app then do not ask me touch id authentication

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "prevent touch id authentication in android if we open camera and gallery from our app only" means.

Comment: means like whatsapp app if we open camera from whatsapp only and then return into whatsapp they didnot ask user to unlock whatsapp again
same functionality i want to implement in my app.

Comment: An app is not asked to "unlock" itself again, by default. So, please explain, in detail, what you are doing in your app that is forcing your users to "unlock" your app again. For example, you might edit your question with a [mcve] demonstrating what you are using for this. Then, perhaps we can suggest approaches for avoiding that code in this circumstance.

Comment: Means i pressed home button then app in in background right?Then i open recent apps then app comes into foreground.Right? Now the issue is When i open camera or gallery from my app then my app running in background and when i return from camera and gallery my app comes into foreground. So, i want that when i open camera and gallery from my app then my app will not run into background.And when i return from camera and gallery will not have to  ask me to touch id authentication.

Comment: "So, i want that when i open camera and gallery from my app then my app will not run into background" -- um, you do not have much of a choice here. "And when i return from camera and gallery will not have to ask me to touch id authentication" -- unless your app is forcing some sort of authentication, simply leaving another app and returning to yours will not trigger authentication, whether "touch id" (which is an iOS thing) or otherwise.

Comment: Sorry,i am not getting you.Can you plz explain in detail?

Comment: What CommonsWare is saying is that it must be _your_ code in _your_ app that is deciding to challenge the user for a fingerprint. Presumably, whenever it is opened/brought to the foreground. If you _don't_ want this to happen after returning from taking a photo, then you must modify that logic to suppress the check in certain circumstances. No one can help you more if you don't show the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Pick Data

```
private void pickContact() {
Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
```

}

handle on Return

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // The user picked a contact.
            // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.

            // Do something with the contact here (bigger example below)
        }
```

}
}

Comment: that's not i am asking